# Storage Spaces With Mixed Disk Classes

Tags: windows-server-2016, storage-spaces

I am building a Server 2016 box for Storage Spaces and have the following disk types:

4x 128GB SSD

4x 300GB HDD 1000rpm

4x 1TB HDD 7200rpm

4x 4TB HDD 5400rpm

Does it make sense to throw all of these into the same pool and create a 2 column 2-way mirrored volume with one of each drive-type per column or is such a variety of speeds not suggested in the same pool?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:

Mixing speeds other than an SSD cache tier is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement is correct. Also, I recommend you to get rid of these 4x 300GB 1000rpm HDDs. They will seriously slow you down.

Answer (score 0):

That was a typo. They are 10000 rpm drives. Not sure if 1000 even exists.

I ended up creating a separate pool with these for a backup repository.

Comment: That sounds like a better plan.